# Jquery tabs - external page in tab (example google)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Is it possible to load an external page in a jquery tab ?
I try this but don't work :

```
<li><a href="http://google.fr"><span>Google</span></a></li>
```

Thanks a lot for your help...

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery tab, its always create a div where your result display.
You have only way to open external link on your page using .

```
<li><a href=ReturnIfram()><span>Google</span></a></li>
```

href  get a string which contain ifram like

```
public string ReturnIfram()
{
   return "<iframe src="http://google.fr"></iframe>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IFrame to display an external Website. Example:

```
<li><iframe src="http://google.fr"></iframe></li>
```